# Mongo document and gridfs file relationship

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, spring-mongo

Currently there is a requirement there is a object - "application" which has the filed: "name", "uploadTime" and "executeFile".

Currently the database is mongodb. I want to use a document

```
Class Application {
     String id;
     String name;
     String type;
     Date uploadTime;
     GridFSDBFile executeFile;
}
```

The Dao layer, when I write save, I find I can not related GridFSDBfile to document directly.
I need first use GridFsTemplate.store save GridDBFile, then use GridFsTemplate.findOne find it by name, and put the object nested in application document. Then use MongoOperation save the application document.

```
try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/testing.app");
        gridFsOperations.store(inputStream, "test.app", "jar");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    Query query = query(where("filename").is("test.app"));
    GridFSDBFile gridFsDBFile = gridFsOperations.findOne(query);

    Application application = new Application ();
    application.setName( "test-app");
    application.setType( "type", "Java");
    application.setexecuteFile (gridFsDBFile);

    applicationDao.save(application);
```

Is there any way to just call MongoOperation?
If not, I think call GridFsTemplate.store and MongoOperation.save need executed in a transaction. I remember that Mongo doens't support transaction. How to do this? Only check the transaction in Java code?

Answer (score 3):

> *I find I can not related GridFSDBfile to document directly. I need first use GridFsTemplate.store save GridDBFile, then use
>   GridFsTemplate.findOne find it by name, and put the object nested in
>   application document. Then use MongoOperation save the application
>   document.*

You got it wrong here. When you save a file in `GridFS`, the storage of the file and its metadata are distributed across two collections namely, `fs.files` and `fs.chunks`. Whenever a file is inserted using the `GridFs API`, the file and its metadata are stored at a single shot.

To give a better picture,

When the below instruction is executed:

```
    gridFsOperations.store(inputStream, "test.app", "jar");
```

`MongoDB` makes two entries, one into the `fs.files` and the other to the `fs.chunks` collections.

one entry is made into the `fs.files` collection:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("545d6699756c779b8cb8b13d"),
        "type":"jar",
        "filename" : "test.app",
        "aliases" : null,
        "chunkSize" : NumberLong(262144),
        "uploadDate" : ISODate("2014-11-08T00:40:57.298Z"),
        "length" : NumberLong(433),
        "contentType" : null,
        "md5" : "5e49ad0614687c7ad343f6f9fe6843b2"
}
```

This entry has only the metadata information of the file, such as the file name and the type. You can even set other metadata information using the `BasicDBObject` class. You want to include the `uploadTime`,

```
DBObject metadata = new BasicDBObject();
metadata.put("uploadTime", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

and save it as below,

```
gridFsOperations.store(inputStream, "test.app", "jar",metadata );
```

Also it has one piece of crucial information, i.e the reference to the document which contains the actual file content, in its `_id` field.

Another entry is made into the `fs.chunks` collection:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("545d6699756c779b8cb8b13e"),
        "files_id" : ObjectId("545d6699756c779b8cb8b13d"),
        "n" : 0,
        "data" : BinData(0,"PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4N
Cjx4c2w6c3R5bGVzaGVldCB4bWxuczp4c2w9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvWFNML1RyYW5z
Zm9ybSINCnZlcnNpb249IjEuMCI+DQoNCjx4c2w6b3V0cHV0IGVuY29kaW5nPSJVVEYtOCIgbWV0aG9k
PSJ4bWwiIGluZGVudD0ieWVzIi8+DQo8eHNsOnZhcmlhYmxlIG5hbWU9InRvcExldmVsIj4NCiAgICAg
ICAgPHhzbDp2YXJpYWJsZSBuYW1lPSJpbm5lciIgc2VsZWN0PSInSGknIiAvPg0KICAgICAgICA8eHNs
OnZhbHVlLW9mIHNlbGVjdD0iJGlubmVyIi8+DQo8L3hzbDp2YXJpYWJsZT4NCiAgICANCjx4c2w6dGVt
cGxhdGUgbWF0Y2g9Ii8iID4NCiAgICA8eHNsOnZhbHVlLW9mIHNlbGVjdD0iJHRvcExldmVsIiAvPg0K
PC94c2w6dGVtcGxhdGU+DQo8L3hzbDpzdHlsZXNoZWV0Pg==")
}
```

This is the actual document, that contains the file content in its `Binary` form. Take a note of the document's `files_id` field. It has the same `ObjectId` as referenced from the entry in `fs.files` collection.

This is how `MongoDB` maintains the relationship between the file content and its metadata. `GridFS` is a mere API to abstract the user from handling the low level implementation.

> *f not, I think call GridFsTemplate.store and MongoOperation.save need executed in a transaction. I remember that Mongo doens't support
>   transaction. How to do this? Only check the transaction in Java code?*

There is no need for the application to create or maintain any transactions for this operation.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand my point. my question is not the file content and file metadata. My question is I have a normal document and this normal document has a gridfs element. I want save the document and cascading save the gridfs element. Or else I must save the gridfs element first then save the document manually. Do you know how to cascading save?

Comment: Thats where you are wrong. You can query the fs.chunks collection for the file always. There is no point in storing the content again in a different collection. You need to re consider your approach.

Comment: @BatScream hi there, kindly can you tell what will be the optimized way to manage data like this : 
User, file.files and file.chunks are three collections , i want specific user with all its related file in a response is it possible.?

{ "name" : "batMan", 
   "email' : "bt@gmail.com",
   "files" : [
       {file1},{file2},{file3},.... so on
   ]
}